# Why is occurring HTTP Status 404, in my project JBoss Tomcat 7 + Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

I'm doing some tests with the jboss 7 + spring mvc, and locally it runs but when I put in the cloud, it features HTTP Status 404.

**/pswebproj/src/main/java/pswebproj/control/HelloController.java**

```
package pswebproj.control;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
// URL Controlador 
// - http://localhost:8080/pswebproj/spring/hello
public class HelloController
{
    @RequestMapping("/simple") // .../pswebproj/spring/hello/simple
    public ModelAndView helloRequest()
    {
        String model = "Message from helloRequest(), UAU!";

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("/hellospring.jsp");
        mv.addObject("msg", model);
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/param") // .../pswebproj/spring/hello/param?prm=sbrubbles
    public ModelAndView helloRequestParam(@RequestParam String prm)
    {
        String model = "Message from helloRequestParam() "+prm;

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("/hellospring.jsp");
        mv.addObject("msg", model);
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/pathvar/{var}") 
    //.../pswebproj/spring/hello/pathvar/sbrubbles
    public ModelAndView helloRequestPath(@PathVariable String var)
    {
        String model = "Message from helloRequestPath() "+var;

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("/hellospring.jsp");
        mv.addObject("msg",model);
        return mv;
    }   
}
```

**/pswebproj/pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>pswebproj</groupId>
    <artifactId>pswebproj</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>pswebproj</name>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>eap</id>
            <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>eap</id>
            <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.2-1003-jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.25</version>
        </dependency>     
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SERVLET -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>               
        <!-- // SERVLET -->
        <!-- SPRING -->        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>      
        <!-- // SPRING -->  
    </dependencies>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be used when 
                invoking mvn. -->
            <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app 
                will need. -->
            <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 'webapps' 
                folder. -->
            <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
            <id>openshift</id>
            <build>
                <finalName>pswebproj</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory>
                            <warName>ROOT</warName>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.apache.maven.plugins
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            maven-compiler-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [3.1,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

**/pswebproj/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml**

```
<web-app version="3.0"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         metadata-complete="false">
  <display-name>PsWeb Example Project</display-name>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springweb</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>  
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springweb</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/spring/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

**/pswebproj/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/springweb-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Pacotes a serem escaneados -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="pswebproj.control" />

    <!--  Define quais anotações estão habilitadas -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

I m using local jdk1.7.0_80 + tomcat 7 . And I can run site with the url  http://localhost:8080/pswebproj/spring/hello/simple

The output is :

**Java Puro: Message from helloRequest(), UAU! 

JSTL: Message from helloRequest(), UAU! 

EL: Message from helloRequest(), UAU!**

**But if I run in the cloud with** http://pswebproj-drinith.rhcloud.com/spring/hello/simple , I have the answer HTTP Status 404.

Comment: have you checked the log files of your app server in the cloud to ensure your deployment was successful ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People don't know what could have happened, redoing the tests to show my teacher, he asked to see the output of the console on the server and looking didn't see nor an error output when I was testing with the normal url again just ran, I don't remember having changed nothing.

Thanks to the forum anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**Spring container has NOT detected your `Controller` class** as you have missed the `contextConfigLocation` path which should point to `WEB-INF/springweb-servlet.xml` for the `DispatcherServlet`, you need to add it as shown below in your `web.xml` file:

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>WEB-INF/springweb-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to replace the value of the web.xml and lauched exceptions